# CRON expression - smallest interval?

Tags: cron

Is it possible to define an interval less than a second with a CRON expression?

Comment: That depends on the cron implementation. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The smallest interval you can describe in a Cron expression is actually one minute. Any less than that and you need to handle the intervals otherwise. How about starting your script and just sleeping for less than and a second between every action?

Comment: That assumes `cron` is very precise in its timing; I suspect its coarse granulity is there so I doesn't have to be.

Comment: Larsman's suspicion is correct. The granularity varies by implementation, by operating system **and** by the load on the system - its not unusual to see cron events firing at up to +10 seconds - I've never seen an event firing before it is scheduled. And given that mistimings are likely to occur under heavy load, there's also potential issues of concurrency to address - this really should be implemented as a standalone daemon if its really necessary (in my experience that is rarely the case - most processing can be handled synchronously)